# Considering large annotator differences, is there an appropriate evaluation metric for segmentation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model-evaluation, image-segmentation

I am doing a segmentation task. There are 5 annotators to annotate the images. However, the segmentation target is a small object whose boundary is hard to delineate. Therefore, the differences of the same images between annotators are large, resulting in a low dice coefficient in evaluating the annotator differences.

Is there a more appropriate (or easier) evaluation metric for small targets whose boundary is hard to tell?